# How to extract username and password form secrets manager to use in psycopg2 connect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2, aws-secrets-manager

My secrets manager is throwing secrets in the below format:

```
{"username":"uname","password":"mypassword"}
```

I want to extract username as password to use in psycopg2 connection string but it's not working. below is my code:

```
username = secret['username']
passw = secret['password']

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="hostname",port='5432',database="db", user=username, password=passw)
```

I see this error : `[ERROR] TypeError: string indices must be integers`

how to get username, password and host form secrets manager to use in psycopg2 connection string?

Comment: Is the secrets manager possibly returning  a JSON string?

Comment: Use `python-dotenv` to deserialize it into a dict

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes its returning json